# Databinding in Angular, understanding in detail

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to Angular and I just started learning it recently. I came across the concept of Databinding in Angular. I was able to understand the syntax and stuff but there were some questions that I couldn't find an answer for. These are the queries I had:

1. When we export a class from the component TS file, we can use the class properties in HTML file. For eg: Databinding a class property to a HTML element works. But how does this HTML element know the class or the class attribute? How does the HTML file have access to it?
2. Why exactly are we exporting a class for a component to be used? Is the component a class too? If yes, then wehen we use the component are we calling that class and this leads to rendering the HTML and CSS mentioned in the component?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question in details requires having an in-depth knowledge about how Angular internally works, but here's a starting point:

I've generated a component using angular CLI:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {

  public myProperty: number = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

So:

> Is the component a class too?

Yes, as you can see from the labels "export class", your component is first of all a regular JS class, which implements the `OnInit` interface, has an empty constructor and defines a public variable.

> If yes, then when we use the component are we calling that class?

Exactly: Angular does a bit of magic (see the next point of the answer), so whenever finds a html tag named `<app-example></app-example>`, it creates an ExampleComponent instance and replaces that tag with the html you defined on `example.component.html`

> and this leads to rendering the HTML and CSS mentioned in the component?

The magic happens just above the class definition: Angular heavily relies on [Typescript Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html), which are an (still) experimental feature of Typescript. Decorators allows you (or Angular in our case) to alter the behaviour of a class, for example by intercepting methods call, property changes (did you just say databinding?) and constructor parameters (and this is how Angular's dependency injection works).
In the `@Component` decorators, which is linked to the below `ExampleComponent` class, you're defining three things:

1. the selector, or tag name that Angular will search in the DOM and replace with your component's html
2. Where to find your component's html, which will be linked to each of your `ExampleComponent` instance
3. Stylesheets for your component's html

So, when a property on your component changes (for example `myProperty`), Angular intercepts that change thanks to the `@Component` decorators you've defined (to understand how, do a little search about decorators), and will re-render his html. Inserting that property value on a paragraph like `<p>{{myProperty}}</p>` is just a matter of string replacement.

So, now you have the answer to your first question:

> But how does this HTML element know the class or the class attribute? How does the HTML file have access to it?

It's not the html that knows which component it belongs, it's the component (or Angular that handles that component) that knows which html has to render and which css needs to apply.

> Why exactly are we exporting a class for a component to be used?

This is simply to let Angular know that we have defined a component. Exporting something from a .ts file makes it available on the rest of the project, and particularly on the `AppModule` file, where you will find your `ExampleComponent` among the declarations array:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ExampleComponent
  ],
// Something else
```

Comment: Wow! Really a very helpful answer man. Really good points. Especially at the end where u mentioned its not the HTML but the angular that replaces the component with component's HTML. Thank you.